# What exactly is the identity tensor of a vector space and how can its trace be used to define the dimension of that space.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For example i would guess it might go something like this. Let P be a vector space of at most rank 3 polynomials.than the identity would be a (1,1) tensor decomposible into parts one of which would be d3\dx3 (f element of P)times 1/6 times x3. Than the trace would be when that map "eats itself."

The main point is to find a basis free coordinate free definition of the dimension of a linear space.

Comment: This is exactly the statement that the identity operator on a vector space $V$ is linear, and that its trace is $\dim V$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\delta^i{}_j$ is the identity tensor, then $\delta^i{}_i$ is its trace. That's the sum of all the elements in the "diagonal" (if you think of tensors as matrices), which are all $1$. There are $n$ of them, where $n$ is the dimension of the space, so the trace is equal to $n$.

Comment: I need a coordinate free reason.